# how to make a fixed nav flush with the top of the window

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with a fixed nav bar at the top of my page. It's supposed to be flush with the top of the page, but isn't. Here's my HTML:

```
<nav>
<a href="#">
<div id="logo">
lorem
</div></a>
</nav>

<ul>
*enough li's to go past the bottom of the screen*
</ul>
```

and my CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

#logo {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    color: #75cc83;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: candara, sans-serif;

}
```

It seems like there are only problems with the fixed nav once I put content in there (the list items, in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `top:0` to you nav's rules:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    top:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xTpBT/1/)**